# What is the difference between area solar radiation and sun shadow volume?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, 3d-analyst

What is the difference between area solar radiation(spatial analysis) and sun shadow volume (3D analysis). Are they both used to show sunlight volume?

Comment: Did you search their help for "sunlight volume"?

Answer (score 1):

[ArcGIS Solar Radiation Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/area-solar-radiation.htm)

[ArcGIS Sun Shadow Volume Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/sun-shadow-volume.htm)

What I make up from their help pages is the following:

- Sun Shadow Volume: Calculates the shadow cast by each feature using sunlight for a given date and time. Thus **it calculates a shadow**.
- Area Solar Radiation: Derives incoming solar radiation from a raster surface. **Thus it calculates the amount of radiation received** by a given raster cell, both direct and indirect([How solar radiation is calculated](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-solar-radiation-is-calculated.htm))

So it seems that your goal determines which tool to use.